# Make my service and program themselves run on startup of Windows

Tags: c#

I'm making a service and a program linked with it. I want to make the service and the program make themselves run on startup of Windows. How can I do that in c#?

I've attempted to change startup type of my service to Automatic, but how can I do this in C#?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you create your Service installer class then in that install classs you need to set the Property to set the startup type to Automatic

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace Example.of.name.space
{
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class ServiceInstaller : Installer
{
    private readonly ServiceProcessInstaller processInstaller;
    private readonly System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller;

    public ServiceInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        serviceInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();

        // Service will run under system account
        processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

        // Service will have Start Type of Manual
        serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;

        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "Windows Automatic Start Service";

        Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
        Installers.Add(processInstaller);
        serviceInstaller.AfterInstall += ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall;            
    }
    private void ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("Windows Automatic Start Service");
        sc.Start();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I also reccomend using TopShelf to make your life easier:
http://topshelf-project.com/

It just makes your code a bit more readable by abstracting away a lot of boilerplate code when registering, stopping and starting windows services.